# How to Center-aligned Texts in Flutter?

Tags: fonts, flutter

Expected output:

[image: I want the output to be like this.]

My current output:

[image: Currently it's like this]

Current output's code:

```
subtitle: Center(child: Text(
                    "Hello, my name is Sam \n I am new here.",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `Text` alignment by using the attribute `textAlign`:

```dart
Text(
  "Hello, my name is Sam \n I am new here.",
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [textAlign](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text/textAlign.html).

```
subtitle: Center(child: Text(
                    "Hello, my name is Sam \n I am new here.",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
```